# Sandan meaning in Taekwon do

Tags: tae-kwon-do, terminology, belt

I found my dad's certificate which says "Sandan" on it.

What does that mean?

Is it a 3rd degree Black Belt?

Comment: Any chance you can edit to add a photo?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Sandan means 3rd dan, or third degree black belt.

In rank systems patterned after the Japanese, dan (black belt) ranks count up:

1. sho (little) dan
2. ni (two) dan
3. san (three) dan
4. yon (four) dan
5. go (five) dan, etc.

A sandan rank is higher than a shodan or nidan rank and lower than a godan rank.

The kup/kyu ranks count down. A first kyu is higher than a second kyu.

Comment: Does tae kwon do use Kano's ranking system then?…

Comment: @Sardathrion Yes, it's the same basic kyu/dan system. The total number of ranks and their associated colors vary.

Comment: TIL … /20chars…

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_(rank)#Korean_martial_arts), 3rd dan is "Sam Dan", following the Korean numbering "Il, I, Sam, Sa, ...". Are you sure the japanese numbers are being used?

Comment: @DanielReis, not sure; only have question to go by.

Comment: Given taekwondo started as bastardised karate, and indeed was sometimes openly referred to as "korean karate" (Google it any you'll find a few old books etc) or by one of the Korean translations of karate - "tangsoodo" or "kongsoodo" - in the early days, it's unsurprising that some old documents may use the Japanese spelling.

Comment: In Korean, "sam dan" would be correct.  However, it is not uncommon to find other phrases in Japanese creep into some TKD schools, and "san dan" is a notable example.  Modern TKD schools tend to stick with English or Korean words, but some older instructors - particularly those who still refer to their style as "Korean Karate", and in many Tang Soo Do schools - will use Japanese phrases.  So, dojo, bogu, gi, bunkai, and katana are commonly used there.  Also, if the certificate's date was before 1945, it would have been ALL Japanese (or English translations of Japanese).

Answer (score 3):

It probably refers to "third Dan" in Korean.

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_(rank)#Korean_martial_arts) and [Wikia](http://taekwondo.wikia.com/wiki/Dan) state that Dan grades are refered using sino-korean numbers:

> When numbering the dan ranks, Sino-Korean numbers are used (rather than traditional Korean numbers). In other words, the ranks are il dan, ee dan, sam dan, etc., not hana dan, dool dan, set dan...

While *Sam* is usually used as the romanization for the sino-korean *Three*, they can vary and *San* could have been used in this case.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a little, the term "*Sandan*" is written in Chinese characters as 三段 (*Sān duàn*, while *Sandan* would be the Japanese reading), or Korean as 삼단 (*samdan*).

- 三/삼 is the number **Three** (3);
- 段/단 refers to  **grades**, **steps**, or **stairs**.

As such this term refers to something like the **third grade**, and refers to the third grade or degree of black belt in most modern Asian martial arts.

(Prior to this system the closest there was to a grading system was a certificate system).